# Why is SetupDiGetDeviceProperty function not working?

Tags: c++, device, wdk

I'm trying to use the SetupDiGetDeviceProperty, but apparently it couldn't find such functions within the setupapi.h. I have looked at the documentation and included all the header and library files, but it's just not letting me use the function... What is going? What is it that I'm doing wrong? Heres the code:

```
//Mainframe.cpp file
#include"DeviceManager.h"

int main()
{
    int iQuit;
    DeviceManager deviceManager;

    deviceManager.ListAllDevices();

    std::cin >> iQuit;

    return 0;
}

//DeviceManager.h file
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <devpkey.h>

//#pragma comment (lib, "setupapi.lib")

class DeviceManager
{
public:
    DeviceManager();
    ~DeviceManager();

    void ListAllDevices();
};

//DeviceManager.cpp file
#include"DeviceManager.h"

DeviceManager::DeviceManager()
{
}

DeviceManager::~DeviceManager()
{
}

void DeviceManager::ListAllDevices()
{
    HDEVINFO deviceInfoSet;             //A list of all the devices
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData;     //A device from deviceInfoSet
    DEVPROPTYPE devicePropertyType;
    //CONFIGRET device;
    DWORD deviceIndex = 0;
    DWORD size;
    TCHAR description[1024];
    bool foundAllDevices = false;

    deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, TEXT("USB"), NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_ALLCLASSES); //Gets all Devices

    deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

    while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoSet, deviceIndex, &deviceInfoData))
    {
        deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

        ULONG tcharSize;
        CM_Get_Device_ID_Size(&tcharSize, deviceInfoData.DevInst, 0);
        TCHAR* deviceIDbuffer = new TCHAR[tcharSize];   //the device ID will be stored in this array, so the tcharSize needs to be big enough to hold all the info.
                                                        //Or we can use MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN, which is 200

        CM_Get_Device_ID(deviceInfoData.DevInst, deviceIDbuffer, MAX_PATH, 0); //gets the devices ID - a long string that looks like a file path.

        SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(deviceInfoSet, deviceInfoData, DEVPKEY_NAME, devicePropertyType, description, sizeof(description), size, 0);

        std::cout << deviceIDbuffer << std::endl;

        deviceIndex++;
    }
}
```

the SetupDiGetDeviceProperty function is called at the bottom of the ListAllDevices function.

Thanks

Edit: sorry, forgot to state the error: IntelliSense: identifier "SetupDiGetDeviceProperty" is undefined

Comment: The IntelliSense error isn't the most appropriate one to quote. I would quote the error that the compiler emits. IntelliSense can get it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SetupDiGetDeviceProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551963.aspx) requires Vista or later, as described in the documentation. You must therefore defined `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` accordingly.

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
```

My guess is that your project targets an earlier version of Windows.

Alternatively you can define them in the project options, or on the command line. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745.aspx).

If that is not the answer then is it possible that you are using an out-of-date version of the SDK that pre-dates Vista?